# AWS AppSync error 401 with userPool in React, but no error in AppSync console

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am getting a strange error, only when I try to run a query in my React app, but it works using the AppSync query console. The userPool is configured properly, and I am logged into the React app as the same user in my pool that works in the AppSync console.

I wrapped my entire App in withAuthenticator like this:

```
import aws_config from './aws-exports';
import Amplify, { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth'
API.configure(aws_config);
Amplify.configure(aws_config);
Auth.configure(aws_config);
class App extends Component {
    ...
}
const AppWithAuth = withAuthenticator(App, true);
export default () => (
  <div className="auth-container">
    <AppWithAuth />
  </div>
);
```

The page I am trying to load runs a simple list query and I log to console for debugging. I also added an Auth check right beforehand the it looks like the auth is correct:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log(await API.Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser())
    console.log(await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listFacebookLogs, {limit: 10})))
}
```

My console output for the above is (with edits to remove identifying info):

```
CognitoUser {username: "james", pool: CognitoUserPool, Session: null, client: Client, signInUserSession: CognitoUserSession, …}
POST https://abcd1234.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql 401

The response payload is: {"errors" : [ {"errorType" : "UnauthorizedException", "message" : "Permission denied" } ]}
```

Now if I log in as the same userPool used in my AppSync console, the query passes and I get my list returned to the query. This leads me to believe the auth is set up properly because the userPool login works in the AppSync console. So confirming that the withAuthenticator login prints just fine right before my query, should indicate I am authorized properly, right?

I have ensured my schema is set up properly with auth, my local amplify cli is synced, the aws-exports match the cloud, etc.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Passed query in AppSync query console:
[image: Passed Query]

Failed query in browser via my React app: (you can see I print the correct authenticated user right before the query)
[image: Failed Query]

The query:
[image: Query]

My aws-exports used for auth:
[image: aws-exports]

The schema:
[image: schema]

Comment: Update: learned something new. If my user ('james' above) is in a userPool Group like he is now, this fails. If I take him out of a Group, the query works! Now how do I get this to work while still having users in Groups? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot! Figured it out. When you create a Cognito Group, it creates a new IAM Role (worthless role). So what I had to do was go edit each Group and set the role to the Auth role that AppSync uses, not using the role it had created. I think alternatively, I can go into IAM and link the Group roles to the appsync moderated identities that I want. This would allow me to limit different groups to CRUD.

Comment: Do you know which role/permissions to add to the User Group? Nothing I try seems to work. At the moment I have assigned the User Group the same role that is currently defined in my `amplify/team-provider-info.json` file. It is the property: `"awscloudformation": { "AuthRoleName": "amplify-..."`. I though it had to be this one because the Policy includes `"Action": "appsync:GraphQL",` and the Resources relate to my `graphql.schema` queries and types. But no luck sadly!

Comment: I ended up not assigning permissions to the role made for the group itself. I changed the IAM role for the group to the `amplify-...-authRole` created by amplify for ungrouped users. So all my groups have the same auth role. The correct way to do it may be to edit the group role (example `us-east-1...devsGroupRole`), but I found that can't be done easily through the CLI so I opted to just have all my groups use the authRole.

Comment: It's been a long time now, so I am not 100% sure, but I think I was able to at least automatically assign cognito authRole in `amplify/backend/auth/cognitoname/cli-inputs.json` with: `"cognitoConfig": { "authRoleArn": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "AuthRole", "Arn" ] }, }`

Answer (score 2):

Groups control permissions to the AWS resources using an IAM role. Anytime Cognito Groups are assigned to any user, we need to make sure the role assigned to the Group has the permissions needed to access the resource.

Here's the reference article in case someone needs it
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html