# AppSync queries work in console but not on React front end I get error: Not Authorized to access <query name> on type <query type>

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have created an app with AWS Amplify. I have populated `schema.graphql` with a simple model:

```
type Hobbit @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

When I run queries/mutations from the AppSync Console they work successfully, but when I try to run this from the client (React / NextJS) I get an error: `message: "Not Authorized to access createHobbit on type Mutation"`

```js
// Front end code:
  const createResponse = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(createHobbit, { input: hobbit })
  );
```

This works on another app I've built, so I'm guessing there's some configuration that I haven't replicated properly. I just can't think what it could be? I guessed it could be an IAM role/policy problem, but I can't figure it out.

(This seems like a similar issue to [AWS AppSync error 401 with userPool in React, but no error in AppSync console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988533/aws-appsync-error-401-with-userpool-in-react-but-no-error-in-appsync-console), but either the solution doesn't apply to my problem or I'm doing it wrong)

Comment: I have a suspicion the problem might have been that I hadn't removed the line provided by default at the top of the file: `input AMPLIFY { globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public } } # FOR TESTING ONLY!`.

Comment: I don't get the point, Amplify creates roles for that, I don't think it's related. Did you pull correctly Amplify in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I hadn't removed the default auth rules at the top of the schema.graphql file. Deleting the following did the trick:

```
input AMPLIFY { globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public } } # FOR TESTING ONLY!
```